# Difference between !on and off in .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, boolean

Is there a difference between the following bits of code:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
```

and

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
```

Perhaps in how they handle null, or something? On the surface level they seem like they should work the same, but I've come across both variations in different sites's .htaccess files.

Comment: `off` and `!on` do the same thing when you use it with condition to match against `%{HTTPS}` variable. In simple words `off` represents "THE HTTPS is Off= the request scheme is `http`  and the `!on` means the requested scheme is not `https`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Perhaps in how they handle null, or something?

Well, yes, the expression `!on` will be successful if `HTTPS` was *null*, not set, or set to anything other than "on" (or rather, does not *contain* "on"). Whereas the expression `off` is only successful when `HTTPS` contains "off".

However, the important point here is that the `HTTPS` server variable is only ever set to "on" or "off" exactly (all lowercase). There would have to be something wrong with your server for this server variable not to be set at all or set to *something else* entirely.

So, whether `off` or `!on` is used in this context is really just personal preference.

See also [my answer](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/118396/1243) to the following question on the Webmasters stack:

- [In .htaccess files, is there any difference at all between “!=on” and “off”](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/118391/in-htaccess-files-is-there-any-difference-at-all-between-on-and-off)

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly the same question! I tried looking for duplicates in stackoverflow but not elsewhere. I've got a few more questions regarding htaccess/rewritecond, you reckon that Webmasters is the best place, or is there an even more specific one?

Comment: @PixelSnader "htaccess/RewriteCond" questions are perfectly on-topic at Webmasters. There is some cross-over with Webmasters, StackOverflow and ServerFault in this regard. Although `.htaccess`-specific questions are edging towards off-topic (but tolerated) on SF, since you are expected to have full control of the server.